NiceTabular - Help to "top aligned" itemize list in cells
I want to add itemize list in cells of a NiceTabular table. I figured it out with adding \Block.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
Colonne 1 & Colonne 2 & Colonne 3\\
\midrule
\Block[]{}{Titre\\ dans un Block} &
\Block[]{}{\begin{itemize}\item item 1\item item 2\end{itemize}} & 
\Block[]{}{\begin{itemize}\item item 1\item item 2 \item item 3 \item item 4\end{itemize}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Tableau 1}
\end{table}

\end{document}


I want to align those lists with top alignement. So I add [t] to the \Block command. Now the bottom rule and the caption is in the middle of the table. I can’t figure it out.
This is my MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
Colonne 1 & Colonne 2 & Colonne 3\\
\midrule
\Block[]{}{Titre\\ dans un Block} &
\Block[t]{}{\begin{itemize}\item item 1\item item 2\end{itemize}} & 
\Block[t]{}{\begin{itemize}\item item 1\item item 2 \item item 3 \item item 4\end{itemize}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Tableau 1}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thanks for your help.

There is no point using the command \Block for the lists in your example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}}
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
Colonne 1 & Colonne 2 & Colonne 3\\
\midrule
\Block[m]{}{Titre\\ dans un Block} &
\begin{itemize}\item item 1\item item 2\end{itemize} & 
\begin{itemize}\item item 1\item item 2 \item item 3 \item item 4\end{itemize}\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Tableau 1}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thanks for your help ! I missed that one ! And thanks for all your work on this must have package.
